# MacOS error from gcloud storage cp -r

Tags: macos, google-cloud-storage

When I do:

```
/path/to/gcloud storage cp -r 'gs://group/file' 'directory'
```

I get an error in a macOS popup:

> gcloud download mac os “gcloud-crc32c” cannot be opened because the
> developer cannot be verified." macOS cannot verify that this app is
> free from malware.

The popup window freezes my download. I only have the option to 'Move to Trash' or 'Cancel'.

I believe the 'gcloud-crc32c' it is complaining about is a temp file for the download.
This only happens about 2/3 of the way through the download (multiple files in multiple folders) in my case.

How do I convince osX to complete the download? I am on osX ventura if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

On your Mac, choose Apple menu  > System Settings, then click Privacy & Security in the sidebar.

Scroll until you see the message about "gcloud-crc32c" being from an unauthorized developer.

Click allow anyway.

Not sure if this is the best way, or why this only happens part way through the download process...

Comment: Instead of posting an answer, I recommend updating your question asking for the correct solution. Also, see this [document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/CRC32CandInstallingcrcmod).